# How to find the amount of item between 2 same items in python list

Tags: python

I have a python list:

```
l1=[7,1,3,4,1,7,6]
```

How can I find the amount of items between same item?

For example ,the amount of items between 7 is 4,and the amount of items between 1 is 2

Comment: Do you need this for one number or for every number in the list?

Comment: for every number

Comment: what if a number appears 3 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l1=[7,1,3,4,1,7,6,3]

chosen_number = 3
number_indexes = [i for i, j in enumerate(l1) if j == chosen_number]
items_in_between = max(number_indexes) - min(number_indexes) - 1

print(items_in_between)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the **index** to get the position of an element.

```
def count_(array_int,element):
    position1 = array_int.index(element) + 1 
    return array_int.index(element,position1) - position1
```

Comment: `index` accepts a start argument which would be better than slicing.

Comment: thank you, i didn't know that, i updated my response.

Answer (score 1):

below is the code that asks the user to input the number and indicate whether there are multiple chosen numbers in the list. I also gave out commands (#) for you to follow in order to understand my code.

```
l1=[7,1,3,4,1,7,6,3]

number_chosen = int(input('Input the number that you want to check -> '))
def gap_between_duplicate(num):
    ### Find the index of the number
    index = [i for i, j in enumerate(l1) if j == num]
    ### Calculate the gap between the numbers
    gap = max(index) - min(index) -1
    ### If else function to provide the output
    if gap == -1:
        return f'There is only 1 of the selected number in the list'
    return f'There are {gap} amount of number between the numbers {num}.'
print(gap_between_duplicate(number_chosen))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `O(n)` to precompute and `O(1)` to get result for concrete number solution. Requires additional `O(n)` memory.

This solution will count items from the first occurrence until the last one (if there are more than 2 occurencies). If there is only one occurrence of a number, `-1` will be returned.

```
l1=[7,1,3,4,1,7,6]

res = {}

for i in range(len(l1)):
    e = l1[i]
    if e in res:
        start, end = res[e]
        res[e] = (start, i)
    else:
        res[e] = (i, i)

print(res[7][1] - res[7][0] - 1) # 4
```